# Is there a pre-publication access for ACM journals?

Tags: online-publication, preprint, acm

After a manuscript is accepted in a journal, usually it takes serveral months before it actually gets actually published. Many publishers now provide online access to the published papars, before they get printed, and even before the typesetting.
Some of the ACM journals have a section called "Forthcoming Articles" in their homepage, but clicking on the articles in this sections leads to nowhere! So, I wanted to know if there is a pre-publication access for ACM journals or not.

Here is an example:

**[ACM Transactions on the Web (TWEB)](http://tweb.acm.org/)**

I have searched for some of the articles of this type in third party pre-print servers, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with ACM Transactions publications, as both author and editor, is that they do *not* generally offer any sort of early access.

I find this rather strange for a computing society, but suspect this may be because they also have [fairly liberal preprint policies](http://www.acm.org/publications/fair-access/acm-fair-access?pageIndex=4): authors can put early versions of their article up on arXiv or similar repositories.  Many ACM journal articles are also extended versions of conference articles, so that is another route for accessing information that you may be looking for.